# why is "Django HTML" not offered as a choice in "Select Language Mode" in VSCode, Windows 10?

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, windows-10

- Operating System: Windows 10, 64 bit
- Editor: VSCode 1.55.2
- Python 3.9.0
- Django * (for now version 3.2)

I'm watching a course (python, codewithmosh).

My folders and files are as bellow image.

[image]

why is "Django HTML" not offered as a choice of language after clicking on the lower-right language indicator?

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance for your helps.

Comment: you need to install the Django Extension

Comment: It's a good course but unfortunately for this didn't tell anything about installing this extension and it confused me that why I don't have Django HTML!!. Thanks, your suggestion solved my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the "Django" Extension.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the extension:

[image: django template]

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30518104)